# ios app with facebook integration and multiple accounts

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, accounts

I'm making an app which is iOS 5 compatible so I won't be using the built-in apple framework.  And I want my app to be able to post to multiple facebook accounts (including pages), similar to how the older facebook ios app worked when you could choose which account you wanted to login to.  Can anyone give me some pointers as this doesn't seem to be so obvious even after spending much time in facebook dev center.